# Embed Power BI - view insights of datasets into web applications

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Power BI has some cool features like NLP and quick insights of the dataset and dashboard tiles in app.powerbi.com. But while embedding the quick insights feature doesn't come. How to bring that feature of quick insights. NLP can be embed I've the code for it. But need help on quick insights.

Comment: Basically what I need to know is when I'm embedding the dashboard I dont get the QnA feature with it. It has to be embedded seperately. SO similarly I need to embed quick insights as well. How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one has any clue on this????

Answer (score 1):

Dashboard Quick Insights in not YET supported in Power BI Embedded.

You can however embed Q&A (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/qanda) as you mentioned to get the NLP capabilities.